# when H is a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I studied when H is a separable Hilbert space, every seminorm is norm;but, if H is not separable, it isnot correct. Is it true? pelese help me

Answer (score 3):

What you say is false. For instance, on every Hilbert space we have the constant zero seminorm, which is not a norm unless the Hilbert space is zero-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that every seminorm on a Hilbert space is a norm. To see a very explicit example, let $H=\mathbb C^2$, and consider the seminorm
$$
\|(a,b)\|=|a|.
$$